# JSON: 500 (Internal server server error) in .NET MVC3

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3, post

I'm trying to get some JSON functionality to work, it's basically as simple as it can be but for some reason I'm getting a 500 Internal server error on my console and the application never reaches the controller. I've tried just about everything, but the code is so simple I've given up trying to find the error by readin the same couple of lines over and over.

Here is my script:

```
            $("#saveAdvisorOption").click(function () {
            // Create a JSON object:
            alert("OK");
            var OptionsModel = { "AdvisorNewsFeed": $("#advisorCheckBox").val() };
            alert($(OptionsModel.AdvisorNewsFeed));
            $.post("/Account/ChangeOptionForAdvisor", OptionsModel, function (data) {

            });
        });
```

Here is my model:

```
    public class OptionsModel
{
    public string AdvisorNewsFeed { get; set; }

    public OptionsModel(string AdvisorNewsFeed)
    {
        this.AdvisorNewsFeed = AdvisorNewsFeed;

    }
}
```

}

And here is my controller:

```
    public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ChangeOptionForAdvisor( OptionsModel option)
    {

        //Return something
        return Json(option, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I have a break point on the return statement but it is never run.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why won't you give us the exception...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably just need to add an empty constructor to the `OptionsModel` class. MVC can't instantiate the class without an empty constructor.

Comment: +1. he needs to specify the dataType to `json`, but that's other story.

Comment: @gdoron because the data will serialized and sent to the controller just as any other form data would and then the MVC model binder will bind it to the `OptionsModel` class. The `dataType` argument is a hint for the return data. The default is an intelligent guess and it's pretty good at guessing json.

Comment: Thanks scottm, that did the trick. Although, if anything, I would've thought the constructor with the string parameter would be needed rather than an empty one. Anyway, it works and I'm happy :)

Comment: @scottm. Actually the _intelligent guess_ isn't working very well, I had problems with it, and I see here many accepted answer with this answer, so it's true... :)

Answer (score 1):

@scottm got the major problem.

That said:

You probably need to tell jQuery you're expecting to get a `json` object:

```
$.post("/Account/ChangeOptionForAdvisor", OptionsModel, function (data) {...});
```

To this:

```
$.post("/Account/ChangeOptionForAdvisor", OptionsModel, function (data) {
    ...}, 'json'); //<======
```

Comment: That should not be the reason for the 500 server error though (this fix is client side, *after* the getting the response).

Comment: @FelixKling. True, added a note