# Ajax post data to server side - Error 500 internal server error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a list of text boxes, that I get with jquery, I am trying to send them to server side via a model.

I pus a break point on the server side (webmethod) but it won't hit...

Help?

This is the code from the page:

```
function CreareCont() {
        var model = {};
        model.Nume = txtNume.val();
        model.Prenume = txtPrenume.val();
        model.CNPsauCUI = txtCNPsauCUI.val();
        model.Strada = txtStrada.val();
        model.Numar = txtNumar.val();
        model.Etaj = txtEmail.val();
        model.Apartament = txtApartament.val();
        model.Oras = txtOras.val();
        model.SectorSauJudet = txtSectorSauJudet.val();
        model.Telefon = txtTelefon.val();
        model.Email = txtEmail.val();
        model.Parola = txtParola.val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", url: webservicePageUrl + "/CreareCont",
            data: JSON.stringify(model),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccessCall1, error: OnErrorCall1
        });
    };
    function OnSuccessCall1(response) { alert(response.d); };
    function OnErrorCall1(response) { alert(response.status + " " + response.statusText); debugger; };
```

as I can see from the console, the model send seems to be ok, it's value is:

```
{"Nume":"asd","Prenume":"asd","CNPsauCUI":"asd","Strada":"asd","Numar":"asd","Etaj":"asd","Apartament":"asd","Oras":"asd","SectorSauJudet":"asd","Telefon":"asd","Email":"asd","Parola":"asdasd123"}
```

And this is the webservice code:

```
[WebMethod]
public void CreareCont(Inregistrare user)
{
    string hash = helper.GetSHA1HashData("123");

}
```

The model is a C# class:

```
    public class Inregistrare
    {
        string Nume { get; set; }
        string Prenume { get; set; }
        string CNPsauCUI { get; set; }
        string Strada { get; set; }
        string Numar { get; set; }
        string Etaj { get; set; }
        string Apartament { get; set; }
        string Oras { get; set; }
        string SectorSauJudet { get; set; }
        string Telefon { get; set; }
        string Email { get; set; }
        string Parola { get; set; }
    }
}
```

After using fiddler I got this error: **{"Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027user\u0027.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary'2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary'2 rawParams)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}**

Comment: Try making `CreateCont` `static`. You should probably also catch and log application errors in your global.asax to help you debug.

Comment: are you sure the url generated is correct ? use some client dev tools like firebug to confirm

Comment: @AshleyJohn yes, the url is ok, I checked it... it's "/Code/WebService/EBusinessWS.asmx/CreareCont" and my webservice is in thoes two folders... it's ok...

Comment: @JasonP how can I catch and log the errors?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=global+asax+application_error

Comment: Give this a try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416916/json-500-internal-server-server-error-in-net-mvc3

Comment: @VivekParekh I use WebForms, stiil I tried it and no change...

Comment: @Andrew see this post and posible solution maybe help you http://tharakaweb.com/tag/500-internal-server-error/

Comment: @WilfredoP I had that done too...

Comment: When not sure what is happening use Fiddler. :)

Comment: Do you have access to the server you are trying to hit? Can you set a breakpoint in the action method?

Comment: @VivekParekh Used fiddler, thank you for the sugestion. Now I have an error text (I have added it in the post)

Comment: @bsayegh yes, the server is localhost. No, the breakpoint does not hit...

Comment: make static of your web method

Comment: @sakir done, now I finally have a more explicit error: http://jsfiddle.net/9BfGq/

Comment: @sakir are you sure? My method is in a asmx file... and here they say the oposite: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5112996/3227909

Comment: Try naming your input parameter in your ajax setup. Something like "data: {user: JSON.stringify(model)}

Comment: I am sorry ,I missed that

Comment: var data=JSON.stringify({user: JSON.stringify(model)}); try this one

Comment: @bsayegh : the Json is ok... if I add the user: ... I gen the error" "Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: user.","StackTrace":"...."

Comment: @sakir I got this error: {"Message":"Cannot convert object of type \u0027System.String\u0027 to type \u0027E_business.Code.Library.Inregistrare\u0027","StackTrace":"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your webmethod need to be Static, unless it is in an asmx

```
public static void CreareCont(Inregistrare user)
```

and json data need to have the same name of the webmethod´s parameter

```
data: '{"user":'+ JSON.stringify(model)+ '}'
```

Include `Public` in your class properties like   `public string Nume { get; set; }`, it´s need for deserialize json in  class object

try this code

js

```
function CreareCont() {
        var model = {};
        model.Nume = txtNume.val();
        model.Prenume = txtPrenume.val();
        model.CNPsauCUI = txtCNPsauCUI.val();
        model.Strada = txtStrada.val();
        model.Numar = txtNumar.val();
        model.Etaj = txtEmail.val();
        model.Apartament = txtApartament.val();
        model.Oras = txtOras.val();
        model.SectorSauJudet = txtSectorSauJudet.val();
        model.Telefon = txtTelefon.val();
        model.Email = txtEmail.val();
        model.Parola = txtParola.val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", url: webservicePageUrl + "/CreareCont",
            data: '{"user":'+ JSON.stringify(model)+ '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccessCall1, error: OnErrorCall1
        });
    };
```

cs

```
[WebMethod]
public static void CreareCont(Inregistrare user)
{
    string hash = helper.GetSHA1HashData("123");

}

public class Inregistrare
{
    public string Nume { get; set; }
    public string Prenume { get; set; }
    public string CNPsauCUI { get; set; }
    public string Strada { get; set; }
    public string Numar { get; set; }
    public string Etaj { get; set; }
    public string Apartament { get; set; }
    public string Oras { get; set; }
    public string SectorSauJudet { get; set; }
    public string Telefon { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Parola { get; set; }
}
```